# Change the text of a SKLabelNode added from the scene editor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sklabelnode

[image]I want to change the text of a SKLabelNode created in the scene editor named myScoreLabel to update a score on collision of two objects. Here's the relevant code:

```
class holeOne: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var myScoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
    var myscore:Int = 0

    func addScore() {
        myscore += 1
        myScoreLabel.text = "\(myscore)"
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        addScore()
    }

}
```

At the moment after the collision the app crashes with "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". What am I doing wrong and how can I do it right? Thanks!

Comment: myScoreLabel is nill from the code you share

Comment: How do I make it not nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From code that you provide `var myScoreLabel: SKLabelNode!` is not created.

Try to create `SKLabelNode` firstly. And then set value.

Example:

```
myScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
myScoreLabel.text = "Test"
myScoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .right
myScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y:10)
addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Or you can connect it from .sks scene.

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
     if let label = self.childNode(withName: "myScoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode {
        label.text = "Test" //Must add '.text' otherwise will not compile
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks, i've added a screenshot for clarity I was hoping I could create it in the Scene editor rather than programmatically. Any idea how I would change the text of a SKLabelNode created in the scene editor?

Answer (score 1):

Great, so in the end I did this:

```
class holeOne: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var myScoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
    var myscore:Int = 0

    func addScore() {
        myscore += 1

        if let myScoreLabel = self.childNode(withName: "myScoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode {
            myScoreLabel.text = "\(myscore)"
        }

    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        addScore()
    }

}
```